# Chained IF statements in javascript

Tags: javascript

Whenever I call a function twice in a row, It only evaluates the second one and leaves the first. Also in a chained IF statement, it doesnt work as expected. It always skips to the'else'. Heres my code

```
if (valNames() && valEmail() && valUname()) {
                l1.hide();
                l2.show();
            }
```

**UPDATE** Here's the full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var cont = $('#cont');
            var l1 = $('#l1');
            var l2 = $('#l2');
            var names = $("#names");
            var uname = $("#uname");
            var email = $("#email");
            var err = $('#error');

            email.blur(function () {
                valEmail();
            });

            uname.blur(function () {
                valUname();
            });

            l2.hide();

            cont.click(function () {

                if (valNames() == true && valEmail() == true && valUname() == true) {
                    l1.hide();
                    l2.show();
                }
            });


            function valNames() {

                if (names.val().length < 5) {
                    names.css({'border-color': 'red'});
                    return false;
                } else {
                    names.css({'border-color': 'blue'});
                    return true;
                }
            }

            function valEmail() {

                if (IsEmail(email.val())) {
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "se.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {'r': '648am', 'i': 'ee', 'd': email.val(), 't': 2},
                        success: function (data) {

                            if (data.data == false) {
                                email.css({'border-color': 'blue'});
                                err.hide();
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                email.css({'border-color': 'red'});
                                err.html("The email you entered already exists. <a href='login'>login?</a>");
                                err.show();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    email.css({'border-color': 'red'});
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function valUname() {

                if (uname.val().length > 5) {
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "se.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {'r': '648am', 'i': 'ue', 'd': uname.val(), 't': 1},
                        success: function (data) {

                            if (data.data == false) {
                                uname.css({'border-color': 'blue'});
                                err.hide();
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                uname.css({'border-color': 'red'});
                                err.html("The Username you entered already exists. <a href='login'>login?</a>");
                                err.show();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    uname.css({'border-color': 'red'});
                    err.html("The Username you entered is too short.");
                    err.show();
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What are each of these functions returning?

Comment: Surely you have to pass a name, email or uname through those functions.

Comment: @doveyg Could be validating the content of a field on the page, or something similar

Comment: Pass the field then.

Comment: @doveyg shouldn't make any difference..?

Comment: you should include code of the functions in the if statement.

Comment: check theupdate, I just posted the full code

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. Twice in a row is `a() && b()`, `a() && a()`, `a(); b();`, or `a(); a();`? Still, in none of those cases is the second evaluated without the first being evaluated first.

Comment: @m4ktub I'm calling the functions directly, since they return booleans after validating, It evaluates as true but the if statement says its false

Comment: `It evaluates as true but the if statement says its false`??

Comment: It's a complete mystery what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: Well I'm not good with english, heres the live script: [link](http://stylernation.org/mlm)

Comment: @Chackle: clearly, but it does mean he can use the function somewhere else.

Comment: Have you considered that possibly the `valEmail()` function does not work? Can you show us what it's doing? Specifically `IsEmail()`.

Comment: @doveyg it does work if I test it individually.

Comment: So what happens when you remove the `valEmail()` from the expression?

Comment: On a side note - given that JavaScript is sequential you should always define your functions before you call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `$.ajax` in the `valEmail` and `valUname` you make an asynchronous request which means the function always returns before the request completes. Since you have no explicit return after the `$.ajax` line the function returns `undefined` which is treated as `false`. In that sense, `valEmail` and `valUname` will always return `false`.

Your best option would be to change the logic entirely and have something like:

```
$.ajax({ // first request to validate email
  ...,
  success: function() {
    ...
    if (emailValid) {
      $.ajax({ // second request to validate username
        ...,
        success: function() {
           if (usernameValid && valNames()) { // direct validation
              l1.hide();
              l2.show();
           }
        }
      });
    }
    ...
  }
})
```

There are ways to make it simpler, and you can make it parallel instead of sequential, but you still need to understand how to deal with asynchronous operations and how to chain ajax requests.

Comment: Wow I never thought of that! Thanks though :)